# What is wrong with this xml serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm working on a project that pretty much takes an xml file and serializes it in C# so that it can be used to format a word document. So far everything has been going great, it's parsing a few thousand xml tags and so far creating an 86 page docco quite happily.

However, i'm on the two last tags that need to be done before the document is complete and for some reason the serialization just isn't working on one of them.

```
- <layout_row>
   - <layout_cell type="attribute">
        <attribute_and_presentation attribute="Name" /> 
        <layout_group is_column="true" label_column_width="100" /> 
     </layout_cell>
  </layout_row>
```

Above is a sample of the xml code i'm serializing

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable()]
public class layout_cell
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type;

    [XmlElement("attribute_and_presentation")]
    public attribute_and_presentation attribute_and_presentation;

    [XmlElement("layout_group")]
    public layout_group layout_group;
}

[System.Serializable()] 
public class attribute_and_presentation { 
    [XmlAttribute] 
    public string attribute; 
} 
[System.Serializable()] 
public class layout_group { 
    [XmlAttribute("is_column")] 
    public string is_column; 

    [XmlAttribute("label_column_width")] 
    public string label_column_width; 
}
```

The problem is with layout_group, for some reason it just won't serialize at all. I've been at this for hours and I feel like I must be missing something quite obvious, but for the life of me I just can't work it out.

It's worth noting that both type and attribute_and_presentation serialize perfectly fine in this class.

Comment: I assume you've actually got some data in `layout_group`? If not, it won't serialize by default.

Comment: What's the definition of your `attribute_and_presentation` and `layout_group` classes?

Comment: [System.Serializable()]

public class attribute_and_presentation
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attribute;
}

And

[System.Serializable()]

public class layout_group
{
    [XmlAttribute("is_column")]
    public string is_column;

    [XmlAttribute("label_column_width")]
    public string label_column_width;
}

Comment: My god the reply for code doesn't work nicely. Anyways, both classes just declare the attributes that are provided in the element. attribute_and_presentation works like a charm, layout_group doesn't.
@SimonWhitehead

Comment: @Jessixia it is always best to  add code to your question not the comments for that very reason.

Comment: None of the public properties have `{get; set;}` xmlserilization uses properties not fields

Comment: It works just fine when I try it.  The simplest explanation is that the object you are trying to serialize just has a null layout_group member.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow Jessixia. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say takes an xml file and serializes it but I assume you mean DEserializes. In any event, here is a working example both directions using the classes you posted.

While I agree with other comments that your **should** use properties, I don't see it as your problem. My example uses fields (it's mostly your own code). In fact the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx) states that it's OK with:

> Items That Can Be Serialized
>
> - Public read/write properties and fields of public classes.

### Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string xml_to_deserialize = @"
    <layout_cell type=""attribute"">
        <attribute_and_presentation attribute=""Name"" /> 
        <layout_group is_column=""true"" label_column_width=""100"" /> 
    </layout_cell>
";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(layout_cell));

            //test desieralization
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml_to_deserialize))
            using (var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                result.ToString(); //breakpoint here to examimne
            }


            //test serialization

            var toSerialize = new layout_cell()
            {
                type = "some type",
                attribute_and_presentation = new attribute_and_presentation()
                {
                    attribute = "some attribute"
                },
                layout_group = new layout_group()
                {
                    is_column = "true",
                    label_column_width = "100"
                }
            };

            using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize);

                Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            }


            Console.WriteLine("done, hit enter.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    [System.Serializable()]
    public class layout_cell
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string type;

        [XmlElement("attribute_and_presentation")]
        public attribute_and_presentation attribute_and_presentation;

        [XmlElement("layout_group")]
        public layout_group layout_group;
    }

    [System.Serializable()] public class attribute_and_presentation
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string attribute;
    }

    [System.Serializable()] public class layout_group
    {
        [XmlAttribute("is_column")] public string is_column;
        [XmlAttribute("label_column_width")] public string label_column_width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, you were right about the deserialize, I always get those mixed up.

Hmm, this is quite unusual because your deserialize code looks the same as mine... I guess that means that the problem stems from the entire XML file... which doesn't really make sense to me, if it is getting to the element in the xml file, then wouldn't the subset of that element act identical to if it's present in part of a larger set?

Comment: When faced with one of those odd problems, I start chopping out parts of the file and try to get the smallest set that produces the error.

Comment: I guess that's going to be the only real option. As for the properties vs fields, both do the same thing. Guess i'll just have to go back to the drawing board. Quite frustrating though -_- have deserialized 20 unique element classes and their attributes quite successfully, and this one element gives me nothing but problems =/ anyways, thank you for your help :)

Comment: So this is kind of embarrassing >_< but, it seems the one part I kept looking at in the word document was the one part where the layout_group wasn't for columns... so, it kinda was working